# Excel VBA - define named ranges

Tags: vba, excel

For each cell with content in range C4:C53 of worksheet "Size Selection", I want to create a new named range, and the name of that range should be the same as the content of that cell.

Each of the named ranges should be formula driven, and has a variable that depends on the row of the cell.

I've tried coding this, but keep getting errors; would you please take a look and help me resolve the issue?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:F20000")) Is Nothing Then

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim range_name As String


    For i = 4 To 53

    If Sheets("Size Selection").Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then

    Range(range_name).Formula = "=OFFSET('Size Selection'!$F$" & i & ", 0, 0, 1, COUNT(IF('Size Selection'!$F$" & i & ":$AZ$" & i & "="", "", 1)))"

    Range(range_name).Name = Sheets("Size Selection").Cells(i, 3)

    End If

    Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: `range_name` is an empty string every time. You need to populate it correctly.

Comment: How so? I'm new to VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your comments in the discussion below, here's what I think you're after:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:F20000")) Is Nothing Then

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim range_name As String


    For i = 4 To 53

      If Sheets("Size Selection").Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then

       ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
          Name:= Sheets("Size Selection").Cells(i, 3).Text, _
          RefersToR1C1:="=OFFSET('Size Selection'!$F$" & i & ", 0, 0, 1, COUNT(IF('Size Selection'!$F$" & i & ":$AZ$" & i & "="", "", 1)))"

      End If

    Next

    End If

End Sub
```

It **might** be wrong on the `RefersToR1C1` part, but it should at least now make sense to you on how to proceed.

Hope this does the trick!!

Comment: Thanks John. I have implemented what you suggested, but instead of naming the range, this renames the cell to N/A and causes an error. Also, need to add sheets("Size Selection") in front of the Cells(i, 3). Can't quite figure out what's not working

Comment: And the first line - The setting of the formula - Does it create unique values for each cell? When naming cells, they have to be unique and follow certain conventions... Just checking on this first before delving any more deeply....

Comment: John, many thanks. I don't want the cell name to change. Essentially, I want excel to check cell C4 and if the cell has content (<>""), then create a range which is named according to the content in C4, and apply the formula to define the range. Then move to C5 and so on until we are at C53.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand... So, are you saying C4:C53 will contain the address of the range to name? And, if so, what name will that range get... Please clarify!!!

Comment: C4:C53 each have names, e.g. C4 is "cookie" and C5 is "cake". I want VBA to check C4; if the cell has content, create a named range called "cookie" and apply a formula to populate it. Then move to C5 to create a new named range called "cake" and repeat until you hit C53.

Comment: But what cells will get that name and what formula will populate it?? This still makes very little sense to me - Do you want `C4` to get the name "cookie", for example, and then should you **overwrite** what's in it with the formula? Please clarify....

Comment: Thanks for your patience John. C4 already has "cookie" in it. A named range in Excel is a range of cells that have a name allocated to them - have a look at Formula -> Name Manager. I want the range to be called "cookie". You can allocate a formula in the "refers to" box of a named range to dynamically populate the range. The formula that I have provided in my code creates a range from Di to anywhere up to AZi, depending on how many cells in Di to AZi have content. The formula is tested and works, so that's not the issue. I need to create a range named after C4 content and apply the formula.

Comment: Then move to C5 and repeat until we hit C53.